# Capitilize first letter of AlertIOS.prompt

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

So i am querying the user for input to save a document that they are writing. I want the first letter of the input to be a capital letter - by automatically toggling on the capital "up" arrow when the keyboard is shown. I have the following code:

```
AlertIOS.prompt('Saving Document',
                        'Please name this document',
                            [{text: 'Cancel'},
                             {text: 'Save', onPress: input => this._saveFile(input)}
                            ]
                       )
```

Just wondering how i can do so. I realise that i can edit the input in the back end and capitilize the first letter there, but i am looking for a method in which the user can see that the first letter is a capital when entering input.

Most IOS apps have this feature and i was wondering how to do so in react native.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `https://lodash.com/docs/#capitalize`, maybe?

Comment: @AnthonyKong Don't think this is what i am looking for :-/ I want the capital arrow to be toggled when the keyboard is opened up.

Comment: I don't think you can do that out of the box as there is no param to set it. You will have to modify the native source file to achieve that.

Comment: I believe this is not possible. React Native does not offer `autocapitalize`-like behavior on `AlertIOS`.

Comment: @PedroCastilho Any idea on a library that would let me do this? Not really keen on creating a custom modal type thing.

Comment: No idea right now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, at the moment there is no way to do this with the AlertIOS component, at least not without getting into native code. But take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-prompt, it appears this might have the functionality you are looking for. You should be able to set the autoCapitalize prop on the textInput using this property:

```
textInputProps (Object) -- Additional props on the input element
```